# Processing a Warc File using Logstash, ElasticSearch, and Kibana

Tags: java, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I would like to parse a WARC file using LogStash. I want to feed the input to ElasticSearch, so that I can visualize it using Kibana. I have tried this:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/tmp/access_log"
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
}

filter {
  if [path] =~ "access" {
    mutate { replace => { "type" => "apache_access" } }
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" }
    }
  }
  date {
    match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
  }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

This help to take an apache log and display it. I would like to know how is it possible to use the WARC file and visualize it using the Kibana.
This is sample WARC file that I would like to input.

```
WARC/0.17
WARC-Type: metadata
WARC-Target-URI: http://www.archive.org/robots.txt
WARC-Date: 2008-04-30T20:48:25Z
WARC-Concurrent-To: <urn:uuid:e7c9eff8-f5bc-4aeb-b3d2-9d3df99afb30>
WARC-Record-ID: <urn:uuid:545709ad-90c5-4c08-9eed-092bdf2e33a7>
Content-Type: text/anvl
Content-Length: 66

via: http://www.archive.org/
hopsFromSeed: P
fetchTimeMs: 47



WARC/0.17
WARC-Type: response
WARC-Target-URI: http://www.archive.org/
WARC-Date: 2008-04-30T20:48:26Z
WARC-Payload-Digest: sha1:2WAXX5NUWNNCS2BDKCO5OVDQBJVNKIVV
WARC-IP-Address: 207.241.229.39
WARC-Record-ID: <urn:uuid:4042c21b-d898-43f0-9c95-b50da2d1aa42>
Content-Type: application/http; msgtype=response
Content-Length: 680

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 30 Apr 2008 20:48:25 GMT
Server: Apache/2.0.54 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.0.5-2ubuntu1.4 mod_ssl/2.0.54 OpenSSL/0.9.7g
Last-Modified: Wed, 09 Jan 2008 23:18:29 GMT
ETag: "47ac-16e-4f9e5b40"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 366
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;URL=http://www.archive.org/index.php"/>
<script>
document.location="http://www.archive.org/index.php";
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img width="70" height="56" src="http://www.archive.org/images/logoc.jpg"/><br/>
Please visit our website at:
<a href="http://www.archive.org">http://www.archive.org</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the full Sample of File: [Sample WARC Text in Text File Format](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzQ6rtO2VN95WUV3YmhUX1JuYkk/view?usp=sharing)
Hope to hear from you soon.. I will be glad if I get this query resolved.

Comment: I think logstash is totally not the right tool for that job. Logstash is for processing Log files or files with the same format on each line, not files like that. Or if you want to extract information from some of the lines, you could indicate what information you want.

Comment: @baudsp Thank you for your comments. But let me tell you, If I want to insert bulk information into elasticsearch then logstash is handy, what I suppose. I have seen many viideos on the internet related to that. But still tere is no solution for the issue that I have.

Comment: "the issue that I have." Which is? It is not clear from your question what you want to extract from the file.

Comment: @baudsp Mostly I would like to extract URL, Date and the connection.
that's it. If I can extract this then I can extract anything

Comment: If it's just that, it might be possible. Could you point me in your examples (the one in the question or the one linked) the exact text of the values you wish to get? Since there is more than one URL and more than one date in the example, I prefer to be sure of what you want before working on a configuration.

Comment: I am trying to get this: WARC-Target-URI: http://www.archive.org/robots.txt and Date: Wed, 30 Apr 2008 20:48:25 GMT and also the HTTP/1.1 200 OK if exist in a line by line manner.

Comment: I've cobbled together a filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This filter will keep only the lines with "^WARC-Target-URI" or "^HTTP/1.1" or "^Date: ", then extract information from the lines.

```
input {
    file {
        path => "/tmp/access_log"
        start_position => "beginning"
    }
}


filter {
    if [message] !~ "^WARC-Target-URI" and [message] !~ "^HTTP\/1.1" and [message] !~ "^Date: " {
        drop {}
    }

    grok {
        match => {
            "message" => ["Date: %{GREEDYDATA:date}", "WARC-Target-URI: %{GREEDYDATA:url}", "HTTP/1.1 %{NUMBER:response}"]
        }
    }

    # For "Wed, 30 Apr 2008 20:48:25 GMT"
    date {
        match => ["date", "EEE, dd MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss ZZZ"]
        target => "date"
        locale => "en"
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        index => "webinfo"
    }
}
```

From the sample file, it will insert in Elasticsearch the following json documents:

```
{"message":"WARC-Target-URI: http://www.archive.org/robots.txt","@version":"1","@timestamp":"2016-11-22T12:55:48.151Z","path":"D:\\better.txt","host":"FREIFDKT0021127","url":"http://www.archive.org/robots.txt"}
{"message":"WARC-Target-URI: http://www.archive.org/","@version":"1","@timestamp":"2016-11-22T12:55:48.151Z","path":"D:\\better.txt","host":"FREIFDKT0021127","url":"http://www.archive.org/"}
{"message":"HTTP/1.1 200 OK","@version":"1","@timestamp":"2016-11-22T12:55:48.167Z","path":"D:\\better.txt","host":"FREIFDKT0021127","response":"200"}
{"message":"Date: Wed, 30 Apr 2008 20:48:25 GMT","@version":"1","@timestamp":"2016-11-22T12:55:48.167Z","path":"D:\\better.txt","host":"FREIFDKT0021127","date":"2008-04-30T20:48:25.000Z"}
{"message":"WARC-Target-URI: http://www.archive.org/","@version":"1","@timestamp":"2016-11-22T12:55:48.183Z","path":"D:\\better.txt","host":"FREIFDKT0021127","url":"http://www.archive.org/"}
{"message":"WARC-Target-URI: http://www.archive.org/","@version":"1","@timestamp":"2016-11-22T12:55:48.183Z","path":"D:\\better.txt","host":"FREIFDKT0021127","url":"http://www.archive.org/"}
{"message":"WARC-Target-URI: http://www.archive.org/index.php","@version":"1","@timestamp":"2016-11-22T12:55:48.183Z","path":"D:\\better.txt","host":"FREIFDKT0021127","url":"http://www.archive.org/index.php"}
{"message":"HTTP/1.1 200 OK","@version":"1","@timestamp":"2016-11-22T12:55:48.198Z","path":"D:\\better.txt","host":"FREIFDKT0021127","response":"200"}
{"message":"Date: Wed, 30 Apr 2008 20:48:25 GMT","@version":"1","@timestamp":"2016-11-22T12:55:48.198Z","path":"D:\\better.txt","host":"FREIFDKT0021127","date":"2008-04-30T20:48:25.000Z"}
```

Comment: Very thankful. But have few questions. Hope you can tell me. I would like to know whether the input taken is file (no JSON) and will this output be written on the elasticsearch with index webinfo? If you can edit and show in the answer, I will be delighted. Thank you once again. And please let me know what is this GREEDYDATA? I came across this for the first time.

Comment: I am trying to insert this output in elasticsearch but it is show error to me.

Comment: Please show me how to put the result in the elastic search. I tried but got errors. I think there is some mistake that I need to check. Is it require that we should have an index already available and having proper data types inserted in it?

Comment: @JafferWilson I added the input & output. Please note that the elasticsearch conf is for Logstash 2+ with an Elasticsearch running locally. The [grok filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html) uses regex to extract parts of a field (here the field message). To do so, it uses patterns, which are equivalent to regex (for example GREEDYDATA = .*, see https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns).

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. I will check it. I think while writing the log, I have made mistake and I will use your code.

Comment: @JafferWilson Glad I could help. I have added to my answer the results from the sample with the filter, using the stdout plugin (`stdout { codec => "json_lines"} `)

Comment: Thank you very much...:)