# Conversion of WARC file to JSON or XML or CSV

Tags: java, elasticsearch, apache-spark, cassandra, logstash

I am working with the WARC files and trying to access the complete file into some framework acceptable format (say elasticsearch, apache sparks or others). But these frameworks accept data in a format of JSON or other types apart from the WARC.
For this reason, I tried the Github program as a parser for the file. Here is the Github repository code link: https://github.com/eugeneware/warc
Now , when I have tried implementing it this program didn't work at all. I don't know what was the problem, but it didn't show up anything. Not an error or an output.
Now I am trying to figure out how I can accomplish my task? If anyone has any suggestions for this please share it with me.

Comment: Logstash can consume direct strings, not sure why you think you need to convert (if even possible)

Comment: @cricket_007 Actually, I tried to input the warc file using Logstash, it takes input and gives very unstructured or you can say the output what I am expecting is not what I get. The output must be like if the file has WARC-Target-URl : http://www.goole.com then the out I should get must be "WARC-Target-URl": "http://www.goole.com" and similar results. And you must be knowing that it takes line by line.. I want to have a data of complete one website in a single set and so on...

Comment: If you could show up the `input` of `logstash`?

Comment: @Kulasangar Yes .. see one of my previous questions has the format of input given: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40715328/processing-a-warc-file-using-logstash-elasticsearch-and-kibana

Comment: @JafferWilson what if you use `type => "json"` within your `input` in `logstash`?

Comment: @Kulasangar But that is not proper for input. As I am interest to feed WARC or json converted warc  to the logstash. But warc is not json. Hence looking for such a mechanism to do this or something else